# AS 400- Sequential File not getting written. No error in the status. COBOL 400

Tags: file, ibm-midrange, cobol, sequential

I'm declaring a sequential file :

```
    SELECT   F-MYFILE ASSIGN       DATABASE-MYFILE
                      ORGANIZATION SEQUENTIAL          
                      ACCESS       SEQUENTIAL          
                      STATUS       WW-STS-MYFILE.
```

In my COBOL program I am opening it as:

```
    OPEN extend F-MYFILE
    IF WW-STS-MYFILE NOT="00"  
       GO TO  FINISH
    END-IF                

    INITIALIZE MYFILE
    MOVE "abcd" TO CONTENT OF MYFILE
    WRITE MYFILE.
```

While I am writing the record the file is not showing any error in the status WW-STS-MYFILE, its '00'.
But still the record is not getting written.
Could you please tell the possible reason for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Wat??


just to add.. i also check the file stack at the time of "write". It is getting open properly

Comment: yes i have checked it in debug.


But ya today when I opened the file in I-O mode write was working fine.. I don't undersatnd why my write is working fine with I-O(Indexed file) and not EXTEND/OUTPUT(sequential file)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with AS/400 as I'm a z/OS developer, but the rule of thumb I've followed is that you read a file, but you write a record. if MYFILE is the filename and not a record layout for that file, then you are trying to write a file instead of a record for that file.

Comment: MYFILE, not a good choice of name, is however, a record-layout. It is the target of INITIALIZE, so cannot be a file. Plus, the compiler would have flagged an error for writing a file.

Answer (score 0):

Does your program CLOSE the file? Is the file under commitment control? If you're using commitment control, and you haven't done a COMMIT or a CLOSE, the record(s) will be rolled back automatically when the program ends.

If you try to view the file while the program is still running, before it CLOSEs the file, it may be a file buffering issue.

Comment: Some interesting thoughts, could be comments. Does the last comment on the Question still fit?